# Starting process and storing handle to window

Tags: c#, winapi, process, window-handles

Would someone mind helping me out with a problem I've been stuck on for a bit? I'm using C# and trying to start a couple processes, and later move those windows to separate monitors.

So far this was the main idea:

```
Process p1 = Process.Start(@"1.pptx");
Process p2 = Process.Start(@"2.pptx");

SetWindowPos(p1.MainWindowHandle, -1,
                        0,
                        0,
                       100,
                        100,
                        SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
SetWindowPos(p2.MainWindowHandle, -1,
                        200,
                        200,
                       100,
                        100,
                        SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

But after trying a bunch of different things, I haven't been able to get it to work. Could anyone give me some pointers?

As a side note which is confusing me, if I print those to process IDs (p1, p2), and then run this code:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
       }
}
```

those process IDs don't exist. I know there must be something simple I'm missing...?

UPDATE: The reason for the problem above is that for some reason the MainWindowTitle didn't have a value, so it wasn't printing the pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are still looking for an answer, this is what I did to get it working.

First, use EnumWindows to get a handle to each open window before starting any new process. Then start your process, then check all windows again making sure they're visible and have window text. If you have only 1 new process, chances are that's your new window. If not, I've tried it 3 times before failing. So far, the code has worked great.

Here is the code for helper functions/Win32 API calls.

```
        public delegate bool EnumedWindow(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumedWindow lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

        public static ArrayList GetWindows()
        {
            ArrayList windowHandles = new ArrayList();
            EnumedWindow callBackPtr = GetWindowHandle;
            EnumWindows(callBackPtr, windowHandles);

            return windowHandles;
        }

        private static bool GetWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle, ArrayList windowHandles)
        {
            windowHandles.Add(windowHandle);
            return true;
        }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x,     int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
```

My main logic then went something like this (adjust as necessary):

```
List<IntPtr> alreadyOpenWindows = new List<IntPtr>();
foreach (IntPtr ip in GetWindows())
{
     alreadyOpenWindows.Add(ip);
}

Process.Start("your command here");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

foreach (IntPtr ip in GetWindows())
{
    // To consider it a new window, it must be visible, it must not have been open previously, and it must have window text length > 0
    if (IsWindowVisible(ip) && alreadyOpenWindows.Contains(ip) == false)
    {
        StringBuilder windowText = new StringBuilder();
        windowText.Length = 256;
        GetWindowText(ip, windowText, windowText.Length);

        if (windowText.Length > 0)
        {
            numNewWindows++;
            handle = ip;
            // break if your confident there will only be one new window opened
         }
    }
}


// Check numNewWindows if you'd like

if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    SetWindowPos(handle, -1,
         this.GetScreen().WorkingArea.X,
         this.GetScreen().WorkingArea.Y,
         this.GetScreen().WorkingArea.Width,
         this.GetScreen().WorkingArea.Height,
         SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

Comment: What was the GetScreen() method?

Comment: This was from a long time ago, but I'm guessing something like `Screen.PrimaryScreen`. Example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/position-windows

Comment: Thanks for a useful link. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Process.Start` to open a document this is handled by the shell. The shell looks in the file association registry and takes whatever steps are needed to open the document.

This may involve creating a new process but equally may not. Office applications will typically reuse already open processes to open new documents. That's what is happening here.

And when this does happen, when no new process is started, the shell returns 0 for the new process handle. That's reflected back to the .net `Process` object. It explains why you have no main window handle.

So fundamentally your basic approach is flawed. Using `Process.Start` will not yield window handles for these documents. You'll have to find another way to locate these windows. For instance `EnumWindows` or a CBT hook. Or perhaps COM automation is the right solution.

As an aside it seems that you did not check for errors when you called `SetWindowPos`. That would have helped you work this out more quickly. Always check return values when calling Win32 functions.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer. If you were trying to locate this window handles, can you suggest what you would do? One idea would be to gather all processes before calling `Process.Start(...)`, then iterate through all the processes looking for the one that wasn't there before. The other idea was to use EnumWindows looking for the filename in the window title. This works for powerpoint files, but may not work for any kind of file. Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: EnumWindows. Then GetWindowThreadProcessId to check which process owns the window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for your answer above; it was instructive. But I don't understand why your comment above suggests using GetWindowThreadProcessId to check which process owns the window. Does it matter? Aren't the processes (Process.Start) already gone by the time they do their launching actions? Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin No. Windows exist in the context of processes and their threads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant to ask, having the processId of the window, what would I do with it in this context? (In other news, I read a old post of yours about COM marshalling on the Infragistics blog. Your article was excellent. I wish I knew more about marshalling and freeing COM resources; it's hard to find the information in one place and there seem to be many rules.)

Comment: @Kevin You'd check that the pid matched that of the process that you just started.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you, I think I understand now. I was thinking about `Process.Start` and the Office apps that you spoke of, where I would not get a processID back because any process that I started would self-terminate as the existing Office app took over. But if I actually did start a new app and found its window, then I could compare their two process ids.